# "unless stated otherwise" or "unless otherwise stated"?

Tags: word-order

1. **Convention:** R^n is always assumed to carry the Euclidean
   topology, unless stated otherwise.
2. **Convention:** R^n is always assumed to carry the Euclidean
   topology, unless otherwise stated.

Which sentence is (more) correct?

Comment: The first one sounds nicer to me, so I'm rooting for 1.

Comment: I prefer to 1st one. Actually I have never seen an example of second one. We know *otherwise* can be used as a sentence adverb. It obviously can be placed in the end of a sentence. So the second one is correct as well.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Both are all right, but from the following [Google Ngram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=unless+stated+otherwise%2Cunless+otherwise+stated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) the phrase *unless otherwise stated* is preferred overall:

[image]

You could, however, just choose to use whichever sounds more natural. Although one is more used, if you are writing and want to use a phrase, use it if it matches your narrative voice. Both are okay because, in English, the adverb can go before or after the verb. The exact placement varies by sentence.

Comment: thank you very much. Hmm, never heard of *Google Ngram*, very interesting. Umm, what does "smoothing" in the program mean?

Comment: (Please use the @ tag so I know you've left a comment) The "smoothing" in Google Ngrams is a statistical analysis tool. You can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing).

Comment: Will use @. As for voting, I can't at the moment, cause I have only 1 point. And to accept an answer, I have to wait 15mins... Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

If you don't see how the second one works, maybe think of *otherwise* as the adverb in the sentence. If you were to say "She spoke **calmly**", it would also make sense to say "she **calmly** spoke". That's how I see it anyway.